# Problems with string split in java (Android)

Tags: java, android, string

When I run this (it's a part of an android app) it works.

```java
String[] hex = new String[6];
        hex[0] = "A4";
        hex[1] = "8A";
        hex[2] = "5B";
        hex[3] = "9O";
        hex[4] = "U4";
        hex[5] = "D8";

 if (hex.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address.");
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex digit in MAC address.");
        }
```

But if I do this:

```java
String[] hex = macStr.split("(\\:|\\-)"); 

if (hex.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address.");
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex digit in MAC address.");
        }
```

It doesn't work...
I've tried to find the problem bit it seems like the first hex isn't the same as the second one; but if I do a println they seems identic.

Comment: And what does thevariable macStr contain?

Answer (score 0):

Use `masStr.split("[:\\-]")` to split around '-' and ':' symbols.

If it doesn't work (I've just test it just in case - it works) - check your input

Answer (score 0):

you are parse a mac address in the form `xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx` or `yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy`
your split method is works. But what you may miss here is initialization of array. Array are fixed length. it should be defined with size.

```
byte[] bytes;
        String macStr="ab:ab-cd:ab:ab-cd";
        String[] hex = macStr.split("(\\:|\\-)");
        System.out.println(hex.length);
        if (hex.length != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address.");

        }
        try {
            bytes=new byte[6];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex digit in MAC address.");
        }
```